# Spring bean unable to resolve constructor for org.joda.time.DateTime

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, jodatime, spring-bean

I am injecting constructor for `org.joda.time.DateTime` using spring as

```
<bean id="myDateTime" class="org.joda.time.DateTime">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.Long" value="${startDateTime:#{null}}" />
</bean>
```

The startDateTime is resolved as `1341571102000`. But I'm getting error regarding unable to resolve constructor

```
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myDateTime' while setting constructor argument; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDateTime' defined in URL [file:/path/to/spring-configuration/application-config.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

Comment: Can you explain me what you are trying to pull of here with that bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `org.joda.time.DateTime` class does not have a constructor that accepts a `java.lang.Long`. You probably want to use the one that accepts a primitive `long`. To do that, try specifying `type="long"` for the `constructor-arg`.

However, the fallback to `null` in case `startDateTime` is not set will not work in that case. I'm not sure what your intention with that fallback is, but you need to solve it some other way if you are to use the `long` constructor.